# REST call in vb.net: how to pass the data in cURL

Tags: vb.net

How I can convert the below code in VB.net. Thank you in advance.

```
$ curl -X POST https://www.drillster.com/daas/oauth/token \
  -d 'client_id=874a16d4ac764ce4a545f0cca4584c63' \
  -d 'client_secret=5782b2e7532b48b5a0798f2ad6644614' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -d 'code=cIEL8h'
```

Comment: Set `content-type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and POST a new [FormUrlEncodedContent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) object, which is usually filled with a pre-built Dictionary of KeyValuePairs that represent the data to send. -- Use [HttpClient.PostAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync).

Comment: Those aren't actual real credentials to the service, right?